# can I use my linux with a GPU driver of Nvidia on a PC wiht AMD GPU?

Tags: debian, drivers, gpu

### Background

I have a mobile SSD with `Debian Testing`, and I use this ssd as my `mobile linux operation system`.

### Problem

Recently I would like learn CUDA. Following most tutorial, I was required to install `Nvidia` GPU driver firstly.

Now that this ssd is my `mobile operation system`, I wish I can launch it in whatever PC, with GPU card either `AMD` or `Nvidia`.

### Question

If I install `Nvidia` GPU driver in my ssd `mobile linux operation system`, can I use it on PC with `AMD` or `Intel` GPU card?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably yes, but what's the point of CUDA if not run on proper Hardware

Comment: @Kiwy I could run CUDA in one workstation of our lab. but I couldn't occupy the  workstation all the time. in that case, I could carry out data analysis or some other paper work.

Comment: You should give it a try, maybe create an alternate entry in grub to enable nomodset on which should disable you nvidia driver and use basic rendering. (though I'm not sure you'll be able to do so).